# How to make a java project from a Websphere ear work with JPA

Tags: jpa, websphere, ejb

I have an EAR installed in Websphere 6.1. Development is done in Eclipse, but using a simple Java project and updating the *.java and *.class files directly to the server. I want to start using JPA, but the @Stateless annotation gives the error "cannot be resolved to a type". What am I missing?
Thank you for your time,
Iulia

Answer (score 1):

You need either to be on WebSphere 7.0, or to have installed the EJB3 Feature pack  for WebSphere 6.1.  You pattern of use of EAR files and plain java projects sounds a little diferent from what I've done. Suggest you start by following Roland Barcia's tutorial, et that going before you experiment with other patterns.

This [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0712_barcia/0712_barcia.html) may be helpful, it relates to WebSphere 6.1 + feature pack.